# Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller not reaching Service(CLusterIP)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430138/nginx-ingress-is-not-reaching-serviceclusterip) I have explained the scenario. I can reach a clusterIP using nginx ingress But I can't reach the same service using Azure Application Gateway Ingress. Bellow annotation is not helping me

```
appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add below annotations to example-ingress.

```
appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "false"
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
```

You can see the full list and examples [here](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/annotations/).

Answer (score 0):

You were using wrong annotation. I have updated your ingress with correct annotation:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple/*
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
                name: apple-service
                port:
                    number: 5678
```

Checkout all the AGIC annotations [here](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/annotations/#list-of-supported-annotations)